# Proving that $AYTQ$ is inscriptible

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $ABC$ an acute triangle with the circumcenter $O$. Let $YQ$ the middle bisector of $OA$ where $Q\in BC$. If $H$ is the hortocenter of $\triangle ABC$ and $T$ is the middle of $OH$ then show that $AYTQ$ is inscriptible[image].

My idea: I have to prove that $\angle TQB=\angle AQY$. I consider the next picture[image]
Let $S$ and $P$ the intersections between $YQ$ and circumcircle. Then it is easy to see that $ASOP$ is a rhombus. Also I know that $T$ is the center of Euler's circle, but now I am stuck.

Comment: Generally $\angle TQB \ne \angle AQT$.

Comment: Hint: T is [NPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_center), so try to prove $AT \perp TQ$ right.

Comment: @auntyello there is some propertiesc of $T$? I need a synthetic argument.

Comment: I mean you wanted to show that $AYTQ$ is **cyclic** as your idea shows ... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $H_1$ is the foot of the altitude $AH$. By the properties of the nine point circle, we have $|TH_1|=|AY|=\frac{R}{2}$, where $R$ is the radius of the triangle's circumcircle. In addition, it is very easy yo see that $YT$ and $AH_1$ are parallel. So, $AYTH_1$ is cyclic. As a result:
$$\angle YTA=\angle YH_1A.$$

On the other hand, note that $AYH_1Q$ is cyclic. Thus,
$$\angle AQY=\angle YH_1A.$$

Therefore, $$\angle YTA=\angle AQY.$$

We are done.

---

**PS: A more clear picture of the problem drawn by online GeoGebra:**

[image]